# Implementing a Preferences NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsbutton

As we all know, there is some sort of "trend" it seems between Mac apps. They all have the same panel on the top of their preferences window:

[image]

I say "trend", because I searched the  [Mac OS X HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000894-TP6) Without any luck ...

So, how can I achieve this look?
(It's easy to use the textured Window .. but, the buttons and how they look when clicked. That's what I want to know)

**Edit:**

Thanks @valexa.

It seems I can only use NSToolbar under a window's titleBar.
I would like to add it inside a custom NSView ?
At least something that looks similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the NSToolbar https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Any ideas on the new question?

Comment: a NSToolbar can only be added to a NSWindow, there is nothing else similar

Comment: Well, I think I can add a custom NSToolbar looking element using OmniAppKit. I am gonna test it now. Thanks for answering the initial question, though.